# Angular 5 - ng-select - input text event

Tags: select, angular5

I use the module  in my Angular 5 application:

[ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)

My use case is that the user gives in a search term and I load search results from backend concerning to the user input.
I can not find an event which fires when user gives in characters.
Does anyone know which event I can use or how I can do this

Comment: So I guess that this is not possible at the moment

Comment: You can use focus event and at that time you can get keywords and call your back end call and updates items for ng-select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the ***keyup*** *event* is what you are looking for.

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable).